# Linux Eclipse C++ build project from command line

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, makefile

Simple problem, I have a relatively large C++ project that was written in eclipse, I committed that project to svn, and checked out the project on another Linux machine via command line.

I navigated to the project's debug folder and attempted to execute 'make'.  The project started building as expected, but began throwing multiple undefined reference errors.

From what I have read, the make file auto generated by eclipse is not intended to be used outside of eclipse.

How can I compile an eclipse project from outside the IDE?

Comment: Perhaps you could include some of the error messages.

Comment: /home/tkcsam/32MarketService/StokedTaskService_CPP/Debug/../src/Utilities/FirstDataClient.cpp:15: undefined reference to `FirstDatans::ServiceSoapProxy::~ServiceSoapProxy()'

Comment: I doubt that will be helpful, but it is like eclipse does some magic that is not included in the generated makefile

Comment: Where does `ServiceSoapProxy` live?  Is it part of the project, or perhaps an external library that you don't have on the new machine?

Comment: It is part of an external gsoap library.  Kinda similar to a boost library.  However, all of the appropriate libraries are installed on the new machine.  It's like the eclipse makefile doesn't link it correctly.

Comment: @tkcsam generally the IDE's have internal makefile that does all the processing on g++ for you ... i dont use eclipse , so am not sure.

You say you are working on Linux Machine , gcc is present by default in most , have you tried your hand on gcc or g++ by your self ?? .....  something like gcc -c prog.cpp and then gcc prog -o prog.o  should work !! It aint rocket science , try it !! ( caution - you will have to include all your libraries manually )

Comment: @NSD, I am familiar with gcc and g++ but my current project has 100,000+ lines of code spread across 100+ files.  I would rather not do this manually.  I would think that I would be able to export a makefile